# Firebase: I have to click 'Continue' button twice to do anything

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Here's my code to create the user and try to reference displayName:

```js
if(m1 && m2 && m3 && m4 && m5 && m6 && m7) {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(function () {
        user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        user.sendEmailVerification();
      })
      .then(function () {
        user.updateProfile({
          displayName: firstname + ' ' + lastname,
        });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(errorCode);
        console.log(errorMessage);
      });
      var name;
      var uemail;
      name = user.displayName;
      uemail = user.email;
      alert('Email verification code was sent to ' + uemail + ', ' + name);   
    }
```

The main if statement here is just checking that all boxes are filled correctly.

I get this error:
`user is not defined` at `name = user.displayName`.

Also,  I have to click the continue button twice or three times before the `alert` shows up. This `if` statement is inside the click listener, however the user is created on the first click.

What's happening here?

Comment: Hello. Question, are you declaring user or are you assigned directly  `user = firebase.auth().currentUser;`?

Comment: @Marlonchosky I don't understand - that line is the first time I've assigned user in the whole file.

Comment: @WazowskiMan You haven't declared user in the above code.
Please declare user initially

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to access `user.displayName;` before it is assigned, as the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` method probably returns a promise, and promises are executed asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

APIs that return a promise are asynchronous and return immediately.  Execution move to the code following the promise, and the `then` and `catch` callbacks will be invoked some time later, after the API completes.

`user` only has a value after `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` completes, and the `then` callback is invoked.  You will have to make sure your code doesn't use it until after that happens.  Try moving the code that uses `user` into the callbacks.

```
      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(function () {
        user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        user.sendEmailVerification();
      })
      .then(function () {
        user.updateProfile({
          displayName: firstname + ' ' + lastname,
        });

        // Move the code up here where `user` definitely has a value
        var name;
        var uemail;
        name = firstname + ' ' + lastname;
        uemail = user.email;
        alert('Email verification code was sent to ' + uemail + ', ' + name);   


      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(errorCode);
        console.log(errorMessage);
      });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks - although this outputs `null` on the `alert`, which still takes 2 or 3 clicks of the button to appear.

Comment: You're saying the entire alert message is null?

Comment: no, just the alert takes 2 or 3 clicks of the continue button to appear, but the message works, apart from the 'name' part